# Prevent selecting empty cells and specific value

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create a code that randomly selects a specific number of rows in a list. The problem that i want to prevent selecting empty rows and some specific value, for example "54555". Maybe someone could help me? Here's my code below

```
Sub Button1_Click()
Dim d As Object, r As Range, vKeys, x&

'get a set of 3 unique numbers
Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
While d.Count < 3
'Define the min,max of your numbers
x = RndBetween(6, 11)
If Not d.Exists(x) Then d.Add x, Empty
Wend

'Create a multiarea range
vKeys = d.keys
Set r = Rows(vKeys(0))
For x = 1 To UBound(vKeys)
Set r = Union(r, Rows(vKeys(x)))
Next
'Select it
r.Select
Selection.Copy
Range("A1").Select
Worksheets("Ausinës").Paste
r.Delete

End Sub

Function RndBetween(low&, high&) As Long
RndBetween = CLng(Rnd * (high - low)) + low
End Function
```

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Check out this post that will help you craft a question that is more likely to be answered: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I'm curious as to why you used a `Scripting.Dictionary` Object instead of just a `Range`? You could use `rng.Rows(RndBetween(1, rng.Rows.Count))`

Comment: I think a Dictionary is used to optimize, like this item: [Optimise compare and match method using scripting.dictionary in VBA](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/142294/optimise-compare-and-match-method-using-scripting-dictionary-in-vba), when you iterate through arrays and want to compare, a dictionary object can make it in some seconds.